# Why does Eliezer address his prayer to Hashem, [24(12)], “Hashem, the G-d of my master Avrohom”?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

Why does Eliezer address his prayer to Hashem, [24(12)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219), “Hashem, the G-d of my master Avrohom” and repeat this formulation in verses 27 and 42. He himself was after all a believer.
In verse 35, he is content to say “And Hashem blessed my master exceedingly…” without the mention of “the G-d of my master Avrohom”.

On 24(12), Ohr HaChaim says that he was confident that in the merit of Avrohom his prayer would be answered and Haemek Dovor says, he starts the prayer with praise of Hashem before making his request as is proper.

Are there other explanations please?

Comment: We also say Elohei Avraham multiples times a day, and we are believers too.

Comment: I'd like to chime in that the Ohr Hachaim's answer is rather strong, on the level of peshat. At the **end** of 24:12, Eliezer says "and perform loving kindness with my master, Abraham." So it is fitting to note at the start that he is addressing the God of Avraham. So to at the end of 27, it ends "Who has not forsaken His loving kindness and His truth from my master". In 42, it is repetition, but note the immediately preceding setup, that Avraham says to him "And he said to me, 'The Lord, before Whom I walked, will send His angel with you and make your way prosper..."

Comment: Yes @DoubleAA but we say "**our** G-d" first.

Answer (score 2):

Being that Eliezer was an emissiary (=Shliach) of Avraham (HaMeshaleiach) - it seems that he removed his own personal identity/Metziut throughout the whole duration of the Shlichut.

Indeed, througout the whole story Eliezer's name isn't mentioned once, and even when he introduces himself to Rivka's family... he doesn't say I'm Eliezer - servant of Avraham, but rather I'm the servant of Avraham.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because he asked for G-d's help bizkhut shel Avraham (in Avraham's merit).